# cp --no-target-directory explained

Tags: directory, cp, coreutils

**Question:** I need a simple example of how to use `cp --no-target-directory`.

I do experience some difficulties in understanding `cp --no-target-directory`. I do understand [the explanation for `mv --no-target-directory`](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Target-directory.html#Target-directory), but I can't really imagine a way to use it for `cp`.

> For example, when the command `mv /tmp/source /tmp/dest` succeeds, there is no guarantee that `/tmp/source` was renamed to `/tmp/dest`: it could have been renamed to `/tmp/dest/source` instead, if some other process created `/tmp/dest` as a directory. However, if`mv -T /tmp/source /tmp/dest` succeeds, there is no question that `/tmp/source was renamed to`/tmp/dest`. ([source](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Target-directory.html#Target-directory))

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default, `cp` tests if its last argument is an existing directory. If this happens, `cp` creates a link inside that directory, with the base name of the source. That is, given the command

```
cp foo/bar wibble
```

if `wibble` is an existing directory then `cp` copies the source to `wibble/bar`. If `wibble` does not exist then `cp` links the source to `wibble`.

If you want to be sure that the copy is always `wibble`, then you can specify the `--no-target-directory` (alias `-T`) option. That way, if `cp` succeeds, you can be sure that the copy is called `wibble`. If `wibble` already existed as a directory, then `cp` will fail.

In tabular form:

```
The target is …             Without -T               With -T
existing directory          copy in the directory    error
existing file (not dir)     overwrite                overwrite
does not exist              create                   create
```

The only difference is that with `-T`, in case the target is an existing directory, the command returns an error. This is useful when you expect the directory not to exist: you get an error message instead of something unpredicted happening.

The same applies to `mv` and `ln`. If the target is an existing directory, with `-T`, they signal an error rather than silently doing something different.

With `cp`, there's a different case. If you do a recursive copy and the source is a directory, then `cp -T` copies the content of the source into the destination, rather than copying the source itself. That is, given

```
$ tree source destination 
source
└── foo
destination
└── bar
```

then

```
$ cp -rv source destination
`source' -> `destination/source'
`source/foo' -> `destination/source/foo'
```

whereas

```
% cp -rvT source destination
`source/foo' -> `destination/foo'
```

Answer (score 10):

You would use `--no-target-directory` if you don't want a source
directory copied *underneath* an existing destination directory, you
want the source directory copied *onto* the destination directory.

Here is an example of a directory copy with and without `--no-target-directory`:

```
$ mkdir a
$ touch a/b a/c
$ find
.
./a
./a/c
./a/b
$ cp -r a b       # b does not exist; becomes copy of a
$ find
.
./b
./b/b
./b/c
./a
./a/c
./a/b
$ rm -r b
$ mkdir b
$ cp -r a b       # b already exists; a is copied *underneath* it
$ find
.
./b
./b/a
./b/a/b
./b/a/c
./a
./a/c
./a/b
$ rm -r b
$ mkdir b
$ cp -r --no-target-directory a b     # b already exists; becomes copy of a
$ find
.
./b
./b/b
./b/c
./a
./a/c
./a/b
```

You can achieve something of the same effect by suffixing the source
directory name(s) with slash-dot `/.` as in: `cp -r a/. b` which copies
source directory `a` *onto* `b` and not *underneath* `b`.

Neither of the above methods are the same as saying "copy only the
contents of the source directory to the existing destination" since,
if you ask to preserve time and permissions, the existing destination
directory will acquire the time and permissions of the source directory.
An example (edited to remove unnecessary information):

```
$ find . -ls
drwx------   Oct 13 13:31 ./b         # note date and permissions
drwxr-xr-x   Jan  1  2013 ./a         # note date and permissions
-rw-r--r--   Oct 13 13:23 ./a/c
-rw-r--r--   Oct 13 13:23 ./a/b
$ cp -rp --no-target-directory a b    # preserve mode and timestamps
$ find . -ls
drwxr-xr-x   Jan  1  2013 ./b         # note copied date and permissions
-rw-r--r--   Oct 13 13:23 ./b/b
-rw-r--r--   Oct 13 13:23 ./b/c
drwxr-xr-x   Jan  1  2013 ./a
-rw-r--r--   Oct 13 13:23 ./a/c
-rw-r--r--   Oct 13 13:23 ./a/b
```

A content-only copy would not transfer the mode or timestamps of the source directory to the destination directory.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following?

```
$ cp -rvT Dir_1 Dir_2
‘Dir_1/File_3.txt’ -> ‘Dir_2/File_3.txt’
‘Dir_1/File_1.txt’ -> ‘Dir_2/File_1.txt’
‘Dir_1/File_2.txt’ -> ‘Dir_2/File_2.txt’
$ cp -rv Dir_1 Dir_2
‘Dir_1’ -> ‘Dir_2/Dir_1’
‘Dir_1/File_3.txt’ -> ‘Dir_2/Dir_1/File_3.txt’
‘Dir_1/File_1.txt’ -> ‘Dir_2/Dir_1/File_1.txt’
‘Dir_1/File_2.txt’ -> ‘Dir_2/Dir_1/File_2.txt’
```

As such, it's just a different way of writing `cp Dir_1/* Dir_2/`. However, it does catch hidden files at the root of Dir_1 that would be missed by a simple `cp *`.

```
$ touch Dir_1/.Hidden_File_{1,2,3}.txt
$ cp -rv Dir_1/* Dir_2
cp: No match.
$ cp -rvT Dir_1 Dir_2
‘Dir_1/.Hidden_File_2.txt’ -> ‘Dir_2/.Hidden_File_2.txt’
‘Dir_1/.Hidden_File_3.txt’ -> ‘Dir_2/.Hidden_File_3.txt’
‘Dir_1/.Hidden_File_1.txt’ -> ‘Dir_2/.Hidden_File_1.txt’
```

Comment: works for me with[out] `--no-target-directory` option: as long as I use --recursive, everything is fine [with `coreutils 8.12` under GNU/Linux]. The main difference seems to be that with `--no-target-directory` the content but not the directory itself is copied [research still in progress]