# How to `cp` with `--no-target-directory` on mac?

Tags: cp, macos, macintosh, gnu

I want to use the default `cp` on my mac to copy a folder to another destination. I want it to overwrite the target. But if the target folder exists, `cp` copies the source *into* the target instead of overwriting it.

[In GNU `cp`, there is `--no-target-directory`.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94831/cp-no-target-directory-explained) The argument does not exist on Mac's `cp`.

I would prefer not to switch to GNU's `cp` because I do not know if it's as fast as Mac's builtin `cp` (or maybe it is? I have not tested it). Performance is important here.

I also would prefer not to switch because that just seems like an overkill solution. Mac's `cp` work for me. There's a guarantee that it's installed on every mac.

Comment: Does your man page for the MacOS `cp` command describe the `-R` option and appending the source folder name with `/`?  Have you tried the `-R` and/or `-a` options? (My MacOS Monterey has these, but I don't know if earlier versions do also)

Comment: For what it's worth, I doubt any `cp` implementation will have significant differences in speed. They have different options and choices on how to handle edge cases, but the speed of the different `cp` implementations is very unlikely to differ.

Comment: @SottoVoce I think your solution works perfectly, just like https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228637/175318 says. Thanks!